# React dynamic import() syntax not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import component using import(). It is giving me error.

I am using [react-loadable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable)
I tried with [react-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-import) package as well but no luck

I tried with below code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import './App.scss';

const loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-3 text-center">Loading...</div>;


// Containers
const DefaultLayout = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./containers/DefaultLayout'),
  loading
});
```

[image: Attached Error Screenshot]

> Module build failed: SyntaxError: ...../resources/assets/js/src/App.js: Unexpected token, expected { (5:7)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check whether you have babel-loader and the dependencies installed, it can be the issue.

Comment: Use `require()` instead of `import()`.

Comment: `require()` does work but now other react syntax is having an issue like `const loading = () => ..` is not valid syntax. @AbhishekKumawat I will chek other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I have a custom Webpack/Babel config for my React application, in my situation I needed to install:

```
npm i @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

And then I needed to add one line to my `package.json` file under `"babel"` > `"plugins"`:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add support for the dynamic import syntax.

Babel has a plugin for this called `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import

**Install the plugin with:**
`yarn add -D @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import -D`

or
`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`

**Then:**
The Babel recommendation is to add the plugin to your `.babelrc` file like:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```